# How to make exceptions to forms authentication in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am trying to create a "heartbeat" page on my ASP.NET MVC 4 system, so we can check on an automated basis that everything is working OK.  All it's going to do is run a simple query on the DB and make sure no exception is thrown, in which case it'll return Json "success", otherwise it'll return the exception message.

The rest of the system is protected by Forms authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie2" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
...
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

But obviously I don't want to force authentication for a heartbeat check.  So I've created a `HeartBeatController`, and tagged both the controller and the `Index()` method with `[AllowAnonymous]` - but still, when I try to access the `/HeartBeat` url, I get redirected to the login page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have an `<authorization>` element in your `web.config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to remove the

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

as I believe the `AllowAnonymous` attribute won't override that.

**UPDATE**

You'll have to add an `Authorize` attribute to the controllers, or as the following article mentions, you can set it in `GlobalFilters`

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx

Comment: What will the other side effects of that be?

Comment: Anything you want protected, you'll need an 'Authorize' attribute on.  You can do this on the `Controller` or `ActionResult` level.

Comment: I just tried it out and it causes exceptions in other places that are relying on it.  Is there not some setting I can add somewhere that specifically whitelists my heartbeat page?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a location with authorization override in your `web.config` like so:

```
<location path="HeartBeat">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178692(v=vs.100)